# Блоки в fixed по скроллу на чистом Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки!
Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом с помощью чистого JS (кроссбраузерно) можно знать высоту скролла, и, если высота скролла станет 200px, то заставить блоки №1 и №3 прилипнуть к экрану и отлипнуть при значении 1000px?

```css
.roditel {
  height: 200px;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 2000px;
  float:left;
  background: gray;
  width: 50%;
}


.block-3 {
  height: 100px;
  float:left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}

.shapka,.podval {
  clear:both;
  height:200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapka">
Шапка
  </div>

<div class="roditel">
  <div class="block-1">
1 Блок
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
2 Блок
  </div>
  <div class="block-3">
3 Блок
  </div>
</div>

<div class="podval">
Подвал
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать для этого замечательный `position: sticky`:

1. С ним вам не потребуется писать JS-код, совсем;
2. Это свойство [поддерживают современные браузеры](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky);
3. Для IE, Edge и Android Browser - есть стабильный [полифилл](https://github.com/wilddeer/stickyfill);
4. Свойство отлично работает с горизонтальным скроллингом и на touch устройствах.

Используется так:

```
.block {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

Ваш пример с `position: sticky`:

```css
.roditel::before,
.roditel::after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}

.roditel::after {
  clear: both;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 2000px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  width: 50%;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.shapka,
.podval {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="shapka">
  Шапка
</div>

<div class="roditel">
  <div class="block-1">
    1 Блок
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    2 Блок
  </div>
  <div class="block-3">
    3 Блок
  </div>
</div>

<div class="podval">
  Подвал
</div>
```

---

## Как использовать совместно с полифиллом:

Копируем [файл полифилла](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilddeer/stickyfill/master/dist/stickyfill.min.js) к себе в проект;

Подключаем скрипт: `<script src="path/to/stickyfill.js"></script>`;

Присваиваем нужным блокам дополнительный класс sticky;

Подключаем полифилл в js:

```
var stickyElements = document.getElementsByClassName('sticky');

for (var i = stickyElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Stickyfill.add(stickyElements[i]);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за предложенный вариант , я не знаю ничего про полифилл , видимо там придется что то дополнительно подключать связанное JQery , чего вы очень не хотелось.

Comment: С полифилом просто работать, дополнил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо , постараюсь разобраться , но пока подожду , может кто подскажет как это устроить на чистом JS.
Вроде должно быть все просто , задать только ограничительну высоту и подключать необходимые CSS , а вот как заставит JS следить за высотой скрола здесь и сейчас , я пока не могу разобраться.

Answer (score 1):

Это несложная задача,

> как заставит JS следить за высотой скрола здесь и сейчас

Есть событие `scroll`, на **window** добавляем обработчик и следим за этим самым скроллом.

```js
'use strict';

var blockOne = document.querySelector('.block-1');
var blockThree = document.querySelector('.block-3');
var check = true;

function checkScroll() {

  if (check && window.pageYOffset > 200 && !blockOne.classList.contains('sticky') && !blockThree.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    blockOne.classList.add('sticky');
    blockThree.classList.add('sticky');
    blockThree.style.right = 0;
    check = false;
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset > 1000 && blockOne.classList.contains('sticky') && blockThree.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    blockOne.classList.remove('sticky');
    blockThree.classList.remove('sticky');
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset < 200 && blockOne.classList.contains('sticky') && blockThree.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    blockOne.classList.remove('sticky');
    blockThree.classList.remove('sticky');
    check = true;
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset < 200) {
    check = true;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
```

```css
.roditel {
  height: 200px;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 2000px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  width: 50%;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}

.shapka,
.podval {
  clear: both;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="shapka">
    Шапка
  </div>
  <div class="roditel">
    <div class="block-1">
      1 Блок
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      2 Блок
    </div>
    <div class="block-3">
      3 Блок
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="podval">
    Подвал
  </div>
```

- В стили добавил класс **sticky**.
- Я сделал даже больше того что вы просили, если блоки не достигают отметки **1000px** и мы скроллим к началу страницы, они вновь "прилипают" на отметке **200px**.

---

Как видно, центральный блок съезжает влево, это не проблема моего кода, а проблема html-разметки. Например эта строка `blockThree.style.right = 0;`уже добавлена, она предотвращает прилипание к левому краю блока номер три. Теперь поправим остальное, например так:

```js
'use strict';

var blockOne = document.querySelector('.block-1');
var blockTwo = document.querySelector('.block-2');
var blockThree = document.querySelector('.block-3');
var check = true;


function checkScroll() {

  if (check && window.pageYOffset > 200 && !blockOne.classList.contains('sticky') && !blockThree.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    blockOne.classList.add('sticky');
    blockThree.classList.add('sticky');
    blockTwo.style.left = blockOne.offsetWidth + 'px';
    blockThree.style.right = 0;
    check = false;
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset > 1000 && blockOne.classList.contains('sticky') && blockThree.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    blockOne.classList.remove('sticky');
    blockThree.classList.remove('sticky');
    blockTwo.style.left = '';
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset < 200 && blockOne.classList.contains('sticky') && blockThree.classList.contains('sticky')) {
    blockOne.classList.remove('sticky');
    blockThree.classList.remove('sticky');
    blockTwo.style.left = '';
    check = true;
  }

  if (window.pageYOffset < 200) {
    check = true;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll);
```

```css
.roditel {
  height: 200px;
}

.block-1 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 2000px;
  float: left;
  background: gray;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.block-3 {
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  width: 25%;
}

.shapka,
.podval {
  clear: both;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
  <div class="shapka">
    Шапка
  </div>
  <div class="roditel">
    <div class="block-1">
      1 Блок
    </div>
    <div class="block-2">
      2 Блок
    </div>
    <div class="block-3">
      3 Блок
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="podval">
    Подвал
  </div>
```

- Добавил в стили у `.block-2` `position: relative;`

---

Вы и сами конечно можете изучить данный вопрос, посмотрите например здесь [**событие scroll**](https://learn.javascript.ru/onscroll) и здесь [**Размеры и прокрутка страницы**](https://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window).